# Angular 8 get txt file with auth header

Tags: ajax, angular, http, get-request

I'm trying to implement a download link for users to download a record in .txt file.

Firstly it was a simple `<a>` tag

```html
<a href="http://localhost:8080/service/api/downloadFile?fileType=daily&trsDate=20190918">download</a>
```

I could download the file from server in .txt format. But I found that it does not bring Auth header. So I tried to use a http get method to fetch it.

**service.js**

```js
  getCdrFile(url) {
    return this.http.get<any>(`${this.env.service}/service/api/downloadFile?` + url);
  }
```

**component.js**

```js
downloadFile(url) {
    this.service.getCdrFile(url).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data);
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

I can successfully call the API with auth head, then I got nothing happened after I clicked the download button but the txt data displayed in the "response" tab in Chrome developer tool. Also, I got nothing from `console.log(data);` inside my http request.

Is there anyway I can download the file? thanks!

(and here is my response detail)

```
# GENERAL
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/service/api/downloadFile?fileType=daily&trsDate=20190918
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8080
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

# RESPONSE HEADER
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=20190918.txt
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Wed, 02 Oct 2019 03:51:01 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Server: nginx/1.15.2
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Comment: after http create a blob using response and download the blob by creating a dummy anchor element and triggering a click on it

Comment: did the solution posted work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Blob response and create a blob url with it and download on the fly.

**Service:**

- Modify your service to receive a blob response

```
getImage() {
  return this.httpClient.get(
    your_image_link, 
    {
      responseType: 'blob', // <-- add this
      headers: {your_headers}
    }
  );
}
```

**Component**:

- On click of your link on the page call your service to get the response blob of your file
- Create a blob url `URL.createObjectUrl` method
- Create a dummy anchor element assign the blob url and name of the file to download
- Trigger a click event on the anchor element
- remove the blob url from browser using `URL.revokeObjectUrl` method

```
downloadImage() {
  this.service.getImage().subscribe(img => {
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(img);
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.download = "filename.txt";
    a.href = url;
    a.click();
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  });
}
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kp3saz

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways to download the file from the server.

1:-) Ater getting a response from HTTP call to create base64 and create a dummy anchor tag and download.

2:-) Modify backend response as download response.